# RxJava: Can I intercept all errors before passing to onError?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I have a stream the performs a dangerous operation:

```
void main() {
    Observable.just(1)
            .doOnNext(integer -> dangerousOperation())
            .subscribe(
                    integer -> {
                        // TODO
                    },
                    error -> {
                        if (error instanceof ExceptionA) {
                            // recover gracefully
                        }
                    });
}

void dangerousOperation() {
    throw new ExceptionA();
}
```

Let's say that I perform this dangerous operation many places in my application. In each stream I have added some recovery code that is specific to each stream.

I now need to add a new error to my dangerous operation:

```
void dangerousOperation() {
    Random random = new Random();
    if (random.nextBoolean()) {
        throw new ExceptionA();
    } else {
        throw new ExceptionB();
    }
}
```

Furthermore I want to recover from `ExceptionB` the same way *everywhere*. In other words I want to handle `ExceptionA` in a stream-specific way, and handle `ExceptionB` in a global way.

Is there a way I can "intercept" an error in *every* RxJava stream *before* it is passed to the error handler?++

If I handle `ExceptionB` in each onError then I'm duplicating a lot of code. If I remove the onError block from each stream entirely, and rely just on the global `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler()` I won't be able to handle `ExceptionA` in a stream-specific way.

---

++ or better yet, not passed to the stream-specific error handler at all and instead dispose of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a function which handles the global error implementations then return a status if it handled the error. Then with the status you can proceed with the other exception cases.

```
 boolean handleException(Exception error) {
     if (error instanceof ExceptionB) {
         // handle the global exception here
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Now from each stream error implementation you can call the above function to handle the global error cases

```
 error -> {
       if (!handleException(error) {
              // handle the other specific cases here
       }
 });
```

Comment: But… all this does is put the if statement in a function; it doesn't intercept the stream before passing it to the error handler, therefore you have to add that function call in *every* stream, etc., which seems to be what the OP is trying to avoid to begin with.